# jquery calling highcharts generating error 17

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to get a gauge from highcharts.com, working on a page I have worked through the example and I can't see what I am doing wrong.  If anyone could point in the right direction.

here is my fiddle

[highchart gauge not working](http://jsfiddle.net/F6XUT/)

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
            <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/highcharts-more.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>       
            <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        alignTicks: false,
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Speedometer with dual axes'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150
    },          

    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        lineColor: '#339',
        tickColor: '#339',
        minorTickColor: '#339',
        offset: -25,
        lineWidth: 2,
        labels: {
            distance: -20,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        tickLength: 5,
        minorTickLength: 5,
        endOnTick: false
    }, {
        min: 0,
        max: 124,
        tickPosition: 'outside',
        lineColor: '#933',
        lineWidth: 2,
        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
        tickColor: '#933',
        minorTickColor: '#933',
        tickLength: 5,
        minorTickLength: 5,
        labels: {
            distance: 12,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        offset: -20,
        endOnTick: false
    }],

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                var kmh = this.y,
                    mph = Math.round(kmh * 0.621);
                return '<span style="color:#339">'+ kmh + ' km/h</span><br/>' +
                    '<span style="color:#933">' + mph + ' mph</span>';
            },
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 1
                },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#DDD'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

},
// Add some life
function(chart) {
    setInterval(function() {
        var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
            newVal, inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

        newVal = point.y + inc;
        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);

    }, 3000);

});
});

});

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your link to highcharts-more.js is wrong.  Should be:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/F6XUT/1/

Comment: Don't forget `https`

Comment: @redolent - I don't understand your comment.  You don't have to use https to access the libraries if your site isn't secure.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong HighChart libraries. The error can also occur if you use [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts) instead of [HighStock](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock).

Comment: I had this problem today, HighCharts did not work, but HighStock did for a certain configuration. Googling the error led me to this site. Therefore I added the problem I encountered here if someone else should encounter the same problem, too. It took me some hours to figure it out (that you have to replace HighCharts by HighStock in certain cases)

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle with Highcharts? Probably you were using old version of Highcharts, but up-to-date version of Highstock.

Comment: sure, here is the version which uses HighCharts and produces the error 17: http://jsfiddle.net/usvnmker/  Here is the version which uses HighStock and works: http://jsfiddle.net/hc6jtjqe/

Comment: I am not sure which part of the config causes HighCharts to fail here, do you have an idea @PawełFus ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime when you have a spelling mistake in `chart.type` value you get the same error
example: `type: 'colmun'` instead of `type: 'column'`