# Error 17 in highcharts : Highcharts-more js file is not loaded

Tags: jquery, highcharts

After updating Highcharts from version 6.1.1 to 8.0.0. I am facing issues for creating charts. I loaded files like in this order, highcharts, highcharts-more, highcharts-exporting, highcharts-accessibility. However only the highcharts file is loaded, the remaining files are not loaded. While creating charts I am getting a script error with below message:

> This error happens when setting chart.type or series.type to a series type that isn't defined in Highcharts. A typical reason may be that the module or extension where the series type is defined isn't included.
>   For example in order to create an area range series, the highcharts-more.js file must be loaded

Could you help me about this?

Comment: One (or more) of the files is not loading properly. Either you've got them in the wrong order, or the URL is wrong. We can't really diagnose any further as you've not given us enough information.

Answer (score 0):

I am uploading my code here.
In app.js file:
var config = {
        baseUrl : "js/lib", //Here I downloaded all highcharts files and kept in lib 
                                                                   with name highcharts
        paths : {
                  "highcharts" : "highcharts/highcharts",
                  "highchartsMore" : "highcharts/highcharts-more",
                  "exporting" : "highcharts/exporting",
                  "highcharts-accessibility" : "highcharts/highcharts-accessibility"
                 },
       shim : {
                  'highcharts': {
                      exports: 'Highcharts',
                      deps: ['jquery']
                  },
                  "highcharts-accessibility" : {
                       deps: ["highcharts"],
                       exports : "highcharts"
                   },
                   "highchartsMore": {
                       deps: ['highcharts'],
                   },

```
               "exporting": {
                  deps: ["highcharts"],
                  exports : "Highcharts"
               }
          }
    }
```

var require = requirejs.config(config);

And in MyCustomfile.js :

define(["jquery","highcharts","highchartsMore","exporting","highcharts-accessbility"],function($,Highcharts,HighchartsMore,exporting,accessbility){

```
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart :{
                          type : "Bars",
                          renderTo : "placeholder"
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: '',
                        style: {
                            display: 'none'
                        }
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: '',
                        style: {
                            display: 'none'
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    series:[]});
  })
```

})
It is not running my side. it showing error 17.(at highcharts.chart)

Comment: "Bars" type doesn't exist in Highcharts library. Maybe you got mistake with the 'bar' series? Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cwkrhsg2/ API: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/bar-chart

Comment: Thank you for reply. I make it as bar , still not working

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your code on some online editor?

Comment: You are getting error #17. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413157/jquery-calling-highcharts-generating-error-17

Comment: Use this `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>`

Comment: Yeah, its working in online editor. But when i tried in my side, It's showing "highcharts-more file must be loaded" like message is coming. But i loaded highcharts-more file. I don't know why it is not loading.

Comment: I think that answer to your issue you can find here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8890, especially jon-a-nygaard (Highcharts core developer) comment: our recommended approach is documented at Load Highcharts from the CDN as an AMD module: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts#load-highcharts-from-the-cdn-as-an-amd-module

Comment: Thank you for response. Still "This error happens when setting chart.type or series.type to a series type that isn't defined in Highcharts. A typical reason may be that the module or extension where the series type is defined isn't included.

For example in order to create an arearange series, the highcharts-more.js file must be loaded." , is showing

Comment: Try to reproduce it online with using the requireJS. Without it, I am not able to help.